# Pulling img bytes (size) ends up in null

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, blob

**Story**

I am getting images (Book covers) from a provider. Sometimes the images display "no image" or is totally transparent. There is no way I can know if the image is a real book cover or not, there is no other data coming.

**Solution**

I have tried to build a script that first check known `width` and `height` of those "no image" images, which I put into an array together with the size in bytes. If `height` and `width` match I make a `GET` request to get `blob.size` and then I check if the image also match the size in bytes. If all match I want to add a "no-book-cover" class.

**Problem**

It seems like after a bit to many requests the `blob.file` seems to become `null`, like after 6-8 matches. Probably the request is asyncros in some way and can not handle it all whitin the syncros loop, but I am not sure. But I do not know how to handle the problem, how I should solve it. Probably I could optimise this in a way that I can't figure out. Anyway, it is the `GET` request and the result of it that bugs out. That is why I am asking for help.

**Code**

(I have commented it for understanding) Edited code after Musa's comment below.

```
      /* 
  Insert file size, height and width size of known "no book cover" images: 
  [bytes, height, width] is the order in the subarray 
  */
  var noBookCoverSizes = [[2724,100,80],[2727,100,80],[154,120,80]];

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    /* Just so we know we are on the right document*/
    if (jQuery('.portlet-queryRecordSearchResult').length && !jQuery('.portlet-catalogueDetail').length) {

      /* Each book cover*/
      jQuery('.arena-record-cover a img').each(function(){
        var img = jQuery(this),
            imgUrl = img.attr('src'),
            imgHeight = img[0].naturalHeight,
            imgWidth = img[0].naturalWidth,
            i;
        /*Run through each post in array*/
        for (i = 0; i < noBookCoverSizes.length; i++) {
          /* Check if width and height match */
          if(noBookCoverSizes[i][1] == imgHeight && noBookCoverSizes[i][2] == imgWidth) {
            var imgInt = i,
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            /* Run GET request */
            xhr.open('GET', imgUrl, true); 
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function() {
              var blob = this.response;
              /* Check if filesize match */
              if(blob.size == noBookCoverSizes[imgInt][0]) {
                /* Add class to parent*/
                img.parent().parent().parent().addClass('no-book-cover');
              }
            }
            xhr.send();
          }
        }
      });
    }
});
```

EDIT:

**For testing**

Run above code in the console at https://arenagodemo.axiell.com/web/arena/search?p_p_id=searchResult_WAR_arenaportlets&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_r_p_687834046_facet_queries=&p_r_p_687834046_search_query=%C3%A5sna&p_r_p_687834046_search_type=solr&p_r_p_687834046_sort_advice=field%3DRelevance%26direction%3DDescending

**If you run the code with:**

`var noBookCoverSizes = [[2724,100,80],[154,120,80]];`

it works, you can see how the transparent and "no image" covers disappears. But they do not disappear if you run it with more array posts:

`var noBookCoverSizes = [[2724,100,80],[2727,100,80],[154,120,80]];`

It also gives error if I remove width/height check. So my conclusion is that something is asyncros and when there is to many requests, it fails. So I am afraid my logical thinking is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that you have a callback defined in a loop using a variable manipulated in the loop. The value of the variable in this case `xhr`(also `blob`) may not be the expected value when the callback executes.
Since the callback will be a member of `xhr` you can use `this` to reference it.
Also make blob local to the callback since it is not used anywhere else.

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  var blob = this.response;
  /* Check if filesize match */
  if(blob.size == noBookCoverSizes[imgInt][0]) {
    /* Add class to parent*/
    img.parent().parent().parent().addClass('no-book-cover');
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited my post above to be able to test.

Comment: Thanks. It is true in one way, error is gone. I do not get `null` as an error now, so something went better. But it still do not make the right result. So I beleive there is a more major problem. It works when the array only have two posts `var noBookCoverSizes = [[2724,100,80],[154,120,80]];` but not when I have three (Two with same `height` and `width`): `var noBookCoverSizes = [[2724,100,80],[154,120,80],[2727,100,80]];` I added a test page above if you would like to test yourself.